# How to use "regular expression" in Google Analytics as "contains"?

Tags: google-analytics

I want to set a goal in Google Analytics which "triggers" when someone visits a page that contains this part of the url, it's in the middle of url structure:

&naytasivu=3&tapaus=verkkokauppatilaus&tapaus2=tilausok&saitti=ahtihuvila&vaihe=4&tnro=

How do I use regular expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In this particular case you can use the whole string** `&naytasivu=3&tapaus=verkkokauppatilaus&tapaus2=tilausok&saitti=ahtihuvila&vaihe=4&tnro=` as a regular expression since it doesn't contain any of the [special characters from the GA regexp implementation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034324?hl=en).

**In general**, the easiest way to test your regular expressions is simply to open up the page report (`Behaviour -> Site Content -> All Pages`), paste your regex there, see which pages come up, and tweak your regex until you obtain the desired result.

**To validate your goal setup** your can click the "[verify your goal](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032415?hl=en#verify_your_goal)" link inside your goal config and see if the reported conversion rate makes sense (**bear in mind that the data can [lag up to 48 hours behind](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=en#DataProcessingLatency)**, although in practice it's usually ~24 hours).

**What usually causes problems in GA with regex** is the `?` in URLs which you must escape as `\?` (once again your example doesn't have it so you're fine), and again please refer to the [list of special characters](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034324?hl=en) to know what to escape